# read json files in several folders into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to read several json files in several folders as in figure [folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjlnc.png) into single dataframe.
This is my code.

```
path= r'C:\Users\Blank\OneDrive\Desktop\AFND\Dataset'


for path, directories, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:   
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                    df = df.append(pd.read_json(file))
```

but I received this error massage as follow.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [84], in <cell line: 9>()
     10 for file in files:   
     11     if file.endswith(".json"):
---> 12             df = df.append(pd.read_json(file))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py:746, in JsonReader.read(self)
    744         obj = self._get_object_parser(self._combine_lines(data_lines))
    745 else:
--> 746     obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
    747 self.close()
    748 return obj

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py:768, in JsonReader._get_object_parser(self, json)
    766 obj = None
    767 if typ == "frame":
--> 768     obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
    770 if typ == "series" or obj is None:
    771     if not isinstance(dtype, bool):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py:1133, in FrameParser._parse_no_numpy(self)
   1129 orient = self.orient
   1131 if orient == "columns":
   1132     self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1133         loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1134     )
   1135 elif orient == "split":
   1136     decoded = {
   1137         str(k): v
   1138         for k, v in loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float).items()
   1139     }

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

can someone help me to fix it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: pls review the JSON file which is giving the error, you can put a print statement `print(file)` before the exception and review the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can read all the files in a directory for a specific extension using the following.

```
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('.').glob('*.JSON'):
    print(f"{p.name}:\n{p.read_text()}\n")
```